# Bug related to CORS - No Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: .net-core, cors

I created a web api in .net core 3.1. It is deployed on iis 8.5 InProcess.
Configured CORS:

```
services.AddCors();
services.AddControllers....
```

and

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseEndpoints...
```

**Problem**
If you constantly make API calls, then everything works. But if you make a request and do not do it for about 10 minutes, and then do it, an error appears:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/api?id=1' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What could be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the full response you're receiving?

It's not certain, but it seems likely that CORS headers aren't being included because the request is actually returning some other kind of error, and that in that case the CORS headers aren't being included. I.e. the CORS issue is probably hiding a separate error from you.

I would take a look in the browsers network tab to try and see the full response when it's failing, as that response might have more info, or using an HTTP inspection tool like [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/) (full disclosure: this tool is one I've been building myself).

You could also try making a request manually from a standalone tool (curl, postman, etc), which would show you the full response pretty clearly, although separate tools might have different behaviour from your browser.

Comment: Console:  
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/union/masterpage' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
main.62b1f.js:2 GET https://example.com/api/union/masterpage net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Network:  
Status (failed) Size 0B No response.

Comment: Response headers: 
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:29:13 GMT

Comment: @unik yes, it sounds like this is what's happening. Something else (not CORS) is causing a 500 server error, and that error response doesn't come with CORS headers. CORS almost definitely isn't your problem here, so I wouldn't focus on that bit of your code. You need to work out where the 500 error comes from. The body of the response and/or your server logs might have some clues, I would look there.